# (UndefinedFunctionError) when trying to login to phx / elixir API

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building out an API using the phoenix framework written in Elixir.  And I can currently can create a user using Postman the app.  And the API sends back a 201 response.

However, when I try to login with the newly created user the API is sending a 500 response.

I'm getting the following stacktrace,

```
[info] Running KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000
[info] POST /api/users
[debug] Processing with KegCopRAPI.Web.UserController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"user" => %{"email" => "chris@example.com", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "username" => "chris"}}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.8ms
INSERT INTO "accounts_users" ("email","encrypted_password","username","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id" ["chris@example.com", "$2b$12$t1MvizA5fNhSvCald/jctedwvvtlI0jbY/s4W75dD/YwKiaJmZYXS", "chris", {{2017, 5, 10}, {21, 20, 28, 896254}}, {{2017, 5, 10}, {21, 20, 28, 903416}}]
[info] Sent 201 in 434ms
[info] OPTIONS /api/sessions
[info] Sent 204 in 37µs
[info] POST /api/sessions
[debug] Simple CORS request from Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is allowed
[info] Sent 500 in 16ms
[error] #PID<0.392.0> running KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/sessions
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function KegCopRAPI.Web.SessionController.init/1 is undefined (module KegCopRAPI.Web.SessionController is not available)
        KegCopRAPI.Web.SessionController.init(:create)
        (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/router.ex:1: anonymous fn/1 in KegCopRAPI.Web.Router.__match_route__/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:277: Phoenix.Router.__call__/1
        (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/endpoint.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (kegcopr_api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/web/endpoint.ex:1: KegCopRAPI.Web.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /opt/elixir/kegcopr_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

And the **session_controller.ex** looks like the following,

```
defmodule KegCopRAPI.SessionController do
  use KegCopRAPI.Web, :controller
  # Note: the below statement squelched the warning about not finding the Repo.
  alias KegCopRAPI.Repo

  def create(conn, params) do
    case authenticate(params) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        new_conn = Guardian.Plug.api_sign_in(conn, user, :access)
        jwt = Guardian.Plug.current_token(new_conn)

        new_conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("show.json", user: user, jwt: jwt)
      :error ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unauthorized)
        |> render("error.json")
    end
  end

  def delete(conn, _) do
    jwt = Guardian.Plug.current_token(conn)
    Guardian.revoke!(jwt)

    conn
    |> put_status(:ok)
    |> render("delete.json")
  end

  def refresh(conn, _params) do
    user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
    jwt = Guardian.Plug.current_token(conn)
    {:ok, claims} = Guardian.Plug.claims(conn)

    case Guardian.refresh!(jwt, claims, %{ttl: {30, :days}}) do
      {:ok, new_jwt, _new_claims} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:ok)
        |> render("show.json", user: user, jwt: new_jwt)
      {:error, _reason} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unauthorized)
        |> render("forbidden.json", error: "Not authenticated")
    end
  end

  def unauthenticated(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:forbidden)
    |> render(KegCopRAPI.SessionView, "forbidden.json", error: "Not Authenticated")
  end

  defp authenticate(%{"email" => email, "password" => password}) do
    user = Repo.get_by(KegCopRAPI.User, email: String.downcase(email))

    case check_password(user, password) do
      true -> {:ok, user}
      _ -> :error
    end
  end

  defp check_password(user, password) do
    case user do
      nil -> Comeonin.Bcrypt.dummy_checkpw()
      _ -> Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw(password, user.password_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You told your router to use `KegCopRAPI.Web.SessionController`, but your controller is `KegCopRAPI.SessionController` (Notice the lack of `Web`). Voting to close because of typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you can see that your router can't find `KegCopRAPI.Web.SessionController`, but you have `KegCopRAPI.SessionController`.

This `Web` namespace was introduced recently in Phoenix v1.3.0-rc.0 to emphasize that you are altering your Web layer of the app.

Also, your controller's code is valid, but you can adjust it to be more up to date with Phoenix 1.3 using `with` clauses and `action_fallback` macro.